# Не понимаю как исправить. Ошибка времени выполнения: Индекс находился вне границ массива

Tags: pascalabc.net

```pascal
var
    f: text;
    schet, max: integer;
    s: string;

begin
    assign(f, '24 варианты 1-4.txt');
    reset(f);
    max := 0;
    begin
        readln(f, s);
        schet := 1;
        for var i := 0 to length(s) - 1 do 
            if ((s[i] <> s[i + 1]) and (s[i + 1] <> s[i + 2])) then schet := schet + 1
            else 
            if (s[i] <> '0') then schet := schet + 1
            else begin
                if max < schet then max := schet;
                schet := 1;
            end;
        close(f);
        writeln(max);
    end
end.
```

В чем ошибка и как ее исправить?

Comment: Не пишу на Паскале, но вижу `s[i+2])`, при том, что идёте до `length(s)-1`. Вы гарантированно при этом из массива вылезете, о чём вам и пишут. В зависимости от правил языка и `s[i+1]` может вылезти. Как исправить - проверяйте логику и переделывайте.

Comment: Спасибо. В этом и оказалась ошибка. Осталось только подправить немного.

Answer (score 0):

В выражении `if ((s[i]<>s[i+1]) and (s[i+1]<>s[i+2]))` в последнем сравнении вы гарантированно в последней итерации цикла вылезаете за пределы длины строки `s` - элемента `s[i+2]` при `i` =  `length(s)-1` не существует.

Исправить можно. Например, путем включения дополнительной проверки на достижение итератором `i` значения `length(s)-1` и, в случае успешного результата, невычисления второй части условия (`and (s[i+1]<>s[i+2])`).